# classnotfoundexception on pubsub tutorial

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I've been trying to get rosjava to work on my Android phone but for some reason, I have not made much success.

What I have done basically was, to download and install all ros related packages, rosjava, and roscore and then going through the tutorial on ros.org to get pubsub tutorial to run. Everything goes fine and I do have both Gingerbread and honeycomb in my project and they are in my build path and and everything builds with no problem, but when I try to debug (or run) the app, it throws some "classnotfoundexception" and program halts and Android reports that program closed unexpectedly.

Honestly, before trying to run pubsub, I wrote an app of my own and tried to get that to run but I kind of faced the same problem except that the error message there was "noclassdeffounderror".

I'm posting also the output of my logcat. If anything else is needed, please let me know.

Thank you so much.

04-09 10:46:29.213: W/ActivityThread(333): Application org.ros.tutorials.pubsub is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
04-09 10:46:29.233: I/System.out(333): Sending WAIT chunk
04-09 10:46:29.944: I/dalvikvm(333): Debugger is active
04-09 10:46:30.043: I/System.out(333): Debugger has connected
04-09 10:46:30.043: I/System.out(333): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-09 10:46:30.254: I/System.out(333): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-09 10:46:30.453: I/System.out(333): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-09 10:46:30.654: I/System.out(333): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-09 10:46:30.854: I/System.out(333): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-09 10:46:31.073: I/System.out(333): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-09 10:46:31.275: I/System.out(333): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-09 10:46:31.478: I/System.out(333): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-09 10:46:31.681: I/System.out(333): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-09 10:46:31.884: I/System.out(333): debugger has settled (1393)
04-09 10:46:32.143: W/dalvikvm(333): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;)
04-09 10:46:32.153: I/dalvikvm(333): Could not find method org.ros.RosCore.newPrivate, referenced from method org.ros.android.tutorial.pubsub.MainActivity.init
04-09 10:46:32.153: W/dalvikvm(333): VFY: unable to resolve static method 115: Lorg/ros/RosCore;.newPrivate ()Lorg/ros/RosCore;
04-09 10:46:32.153: D/dalvikvm(333): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0000
04-09 10:46:32.153: D/dalvikvm(333): VFY: dead code 0x0003-0035 in Lorg/ros/android/tutorial/pubsub/MainActivity;.init (Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;)V
04-09 10:46:32.163: I/dalvikvm(333): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/views/RosTextView; interface 141 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMain;'
04-09 10:46:32.163: W/dalvikvm(333): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/views/RosTextView;' failed
04-09 10:46:32.173: E/dalvikvm(333): Could not find class 'org.ros.android.views.RosTextView', referenced from method org.ros.android.tutorial.pubsub.MainActivity.onCreate
04-09 10:46:32.173: W/dalvikvm(333): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 120 (Lorg/ros/android/views/RosTextView;) in Lorg/ros/android/tutorial/pubsub/MainActivity;
04-09 10:46:32.173: D/dalvikvm(333): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000e
04-09 10:46:32.173: D/dalvikvm(333): VFY: dead code 0x0010-002a in Lorg/ros/android/tutorial/pubsub/MainActivity;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
04-09 10:46:32.193: I/dalvikvm(333): Could not find method org.ros.RosCore.shutdown, referenced from method org.ros.android.tutorial.pubsub.MainActivity.onDestroy
04-09 10:46:32.193: W/dalvikvm(333): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 116: Lorg/ros/RosCore;.shutdown ()V
04-09 10:46:32.203: D/dalvikvm(333): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0005
04-09 10:46:32.203: D/dalvikvm(333): VFY: dead code 0x0008-0008 in Lorg/ros/android/tutorial/pubsub/MainActivity;.onDestroy ()V
04-09 10:46:32.223: I/dalvikvm(333): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService; interface 142 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;'
04-09 10:46:32.223: W/dalvikvm(333): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;' failed
04-09 10:46:32.233: W/dalvikvm(333): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;)
04-09 10:46:32.243: I/dalvikvm(333): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService; interface 142 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;'
04-09 10:46:32.243: W/dalvikvm(333): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;' failed
04-09 10:46:32.263: I/dalvikvm(333): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService; interface 142 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;'
04-09 10:46:32.263: W/dalvikvm(333): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;' failed
04-09 10:46:32.283: I/dalvikvm(333): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService; interface 142 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;'
04-09 10:46:32.283: W/dalvikvm(333): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;' failed
04-09 10:46:32.315: W/dalvikvm(333): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;)
04-09 10:46:32.323: I/dalvikvm(333): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService; interface 142 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;'
04-09 10:46:32.323: W/dalvikvm(333): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;' failed
04-09 10:46:32.333: E/dalvikvm(333): Could not find class 'org.ros.android.NodeRunnerService', referenced from method org.ros.android.RosActivity.startNodeRunnerService
04-09 10:46:32.333: W/dalvikvm(333): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 94 (Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;) in Lorg/ros/android/RosActivity;
04-09 10:46:32.333: D/dalvikvm(333): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0002
04-09 10:46:32.333: D/dalvikvm(333): VFY: dead code 0x0004-0029 in Lorg/ros/android/RosActivity;.startNodeRunnerService ()V
04-09 10:46:32.354: I/dalvikvm(333): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService; interface 142 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;'
04-09 10:46:32.354: W/dalvikvm(333): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;' failed
04-09 10:46:32.387: I/dalvikvm(333): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService; interface 142 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;'
04-09 10:46:32.387: W/dalvikvm(333): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;' failed
04-09 10:46:32.433: I/dalvikvm(333): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService; interface 142 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;'
04-09 10:46:32.433: W/dalvikvm(333): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;' failed
04-09 10:46:32.453: I/dalvikvm(333): Could not find method org.ros.android.NodeRunnerService.shutdown, referenced from method org.ros.android.RosActivity.onDestroy
04-09 10:46:32.453: W/dalvikvm(333): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 159: Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;.shutdown ()V
04-09 10:46:32.453: D/dalvikvm(333): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
04-09 10:46:32.483: D/dalvikvm(333): VFY: dead code 0x0009-0010 in Lorg/ros/android/RosActivity;.onDestroy ()V
04-09 10:46:32.513: I/dalvikvm(333): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService; interface 142 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;'
04-09 10:46:32.513: W/dalvikvm(333): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;' failed
04-09 10:46:32.534: I/dalvikvm(333): Could not find method com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument, referenced from method org.ros.android.RosActivity.startActivityForResult
04-09 10:46:32.534: W/dalvikvm(333): VFY: unable to resolve static method 83: Lcom/google/common/base/Preconditions;.checkArgument (Z)V
04-09 10:46:32.534: D/dalvikvm(333): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0006
04-09 10:46:32.534: D/dalvikvm(333): VFY: dead code 0x0009-0009 in Lorg/ros/android/RosActivity;.startActivityForResult (Landroid/content/Intent;I)V
04-09 10:46:32.574: I/dalvikvm(333): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService; interface 142 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;'
04-09 10:46:32.574: W/dalvikvm(333): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;' failed
04-09 10:46:32.584: W/dalvikvm(333): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;)
04-09 10:46:32.594: I/dalvikvm(333): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService; interface 142 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;'
04-09 10:46:32.594: W/dalvikvm(333): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;' failed
04-09 10:46:32.627: W/dalvikvm(333): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;)
04-09 10:46:32.654: I/dalvikvm(333): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService; interface 142 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;'
04-09 10:46:32.654: W/dalvikvm(333): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;' failed
04-09 10:46:32.654: W/dalvikvm(333): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;)
04-09 10:46:32.674: I/dalvikvm(333): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService; interface 142 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;'
04-09 10:46:32.674: W/dalvikvm(333): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;' failed
04-09 10:46:32.697: I/dalvikvm(333): Could not find method org.ros.android.NodeRunnerService.addListener, referenced from method org.ros.android.RosActivity$NodeRunnerServiceConnection.onServiceConnected
04-09 10:46:32.704: W/dalvikvm(333): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 150: Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;.addListener (Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerServiceListener;)V
04-09 10:46:32.704: D/dalvikvm(333): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0016
04-09 10:46:32.704: D/dalvikvm(333): VFY: dead code 0x0019-0033 in Lorg/ros/android/RosActivity$NodeRunnerServiceConnection;.onServiceConnected (Landroid/content/ComponentName;Landroid/os/IBinder;)V
04-09 10:46:32.954: I/dalvikvm(333): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/views/RosTextView; interface 141 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMain;'
04-09 10:46:32.954: W/dalvikvm(333): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/views/RosTextView;' failed
04-09 10:46:32.994: D/AndroidRuntime(333): Shutting down VM
04-09 10:46:32.994: W/dalvikvm(333): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.ros.tutorials.pubsub/org.ros.android.tutorial.pubsub.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class org.ros.android.views.RosTextView
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class org.ros.android.views.RosTextView
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at org.ros.android.tutorial.pubsub.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  ... 11 more
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ros.android.views.RosTextView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/org.ros.tutorials.pubsub-2.apk]
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
04-09 10:46:33.253: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  ... 20 more
04-09 10:58:24.363: W/dalvikvm(343): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;)
04-09 10:58:24.443: I/dalvikvm(343): Could not find method org.ros.RosCore.newPrivate, referenced from method org.ros.android.tutorial.pubsub.MainActivity.init
04-09 10:58:24.443: W/dalvikvm(343): VFY: unable to resolve static method 115: Lorg/ros/RosCore;.newPrivate ()Lorg/ros/RosCore;
04-09 10:58:24.443: D/dalvikvm(343): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0000
04-09 10:58:24.443: D/dalvikvm(343): VFY: dead code 0x0003-0035 in Lorg/ros/android/tutorial/pubsub/MainActivity;.init (Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;)V
04-09 10:58:24.473: I/dalvikvm(343): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/views/RosTextView; interface 141 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMain;'
04-09 10:58:24.473: W/dalvikvm(343): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/views/RosTextView;' failed
04-09 10:58:24.483: E/dalvikvm(343): Could not find class 'org.ros.android.views.RosTextView', referenced from method org.ros.android.tutorial.pubsub.MainActivity.onCreate
04-09 10:58:24.483: W/dalvikvm(343): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 120 (Lorg/ros/android/views/RosTextView;) in Lorg/ros/android/tutorial/pubsub/MainActivity;
04-09 10:58:24.493: D/dalvikvm(343): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000e
04-09 10:58:24.493: D/dalvikvm(343): VFY: dead code 0x0010-002a in Lorg/ros/android/tutorial/pubsub/MainActivity;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
04-09 10:58:24.493: I/dalvikvm(343): Could not find method org.ros.RosCore.shutdown, referenced from method org.ros.android.tutorial.pubsub.MainActivity.onDestroy
04-09 10:58:24.533: W/dalvikvm(343): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 116: Lorg/ros/RosCore;.shutdown ()V
04-09 10:58:24.533: D/dalvikvm(343): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0005
04-09 10:58:24.533: D/dalvikvm(343): VFY: dead code 0x0008-0008 in Lorg/ros/android/tutorial/pubsub/MainActivity;.onDestroy ()V
04-09 10:58:24.533: I/dalvikvm(343): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService; interface 142 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;'
04-09 10:58:24.563: W/dalvikvm(343): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;' failed
04-09 10:58:24.574: W/dalvikvm(343): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;)
04-09 10:58:24.574: I/dalvikvm(343): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService; interface 142 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;'
04-09 10:58:24.574: W/dalvikvm(343): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;' failed
04-09 10:58:24.583: I/dalvikvm(343): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService; interface 142 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;'
04-09 10:58:24.583: W/dalvikvm(343): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;' failed
04-09 10:58:24.593: I/dalvikvm(343): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService; interface 142 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;'
04-09 10:58:24.593: W/dalvikvm(343): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;' failed
04-09 10:58:24.593: W/dalvikvm(343): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;)
04-09 10:58:24.593: I/dalvikvm(343): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService; interface 142 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;'
04-09 10:58:24.603: W/dalvikvm(343): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;' failed
04-09 10:58:24.603: E/dalvikvm(343): Could not find class 'org.ros.android.NodeRunnerService', referenced from method org.ros.android.RosActivity.startNodeRunnerService
04-09 10:58:24.603: W/dalvikvm(343): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 94 (Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;) in Lorg/ros/android/RosActivity;
04-09 10:58:24.603: D/dalvikvm(343): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0002
04-09 10:58:24.603: D/dalvikvm(343): VFY: dead code 0x0004-0029 in Lorg/ros/android/RosActivity;.startNodeRunnerService ()V
04-09 10:58:24.613: I/dalvikvm(343): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService; interface 142 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;'
04-09 10:58:24.613: W/dalvikvm(343): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;' failed
04-09 10:58:24.624: I/dalvikvm(343): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService; interface 142 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;'
04-09 10:58:24.624: W/dalvikvm(343): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;' failed
04-09 10:58:24.633: I/dalvikvm(343): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService; interface 142 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;'
04-09 10:58:24.633: W/dalvikvm(343): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;' failed
04-09 10:58:24.633: I/dalvikvm(343): Could not find method org.ros.android.NodeRunnerService.shutdown, referenced from method org.ros.android.RosActivity.onDestroy
04-09 10:58:24.643: W/dalvikvm(343): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 159: Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;.shutdown ()V
04-09 10:58:24.643: D/dalvikvm(343): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
04-09 10:58:24.643: D/dalvikvm(343): VFY: dead code 0x0009-0010 in Lorg/ros/android/RosActivity;.onDestroy ()V
04-09 10:58:24.654: I/dalvikvm(343): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService; interface 142 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;'
04-09 10:58:24.654: W/dalvikvm(343): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;' failed
04-09 10:58:24.663: I/dalvikvm(343): Could not find method com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument, referenced from method org.ros.android.RosActivity.startActivityForResult
04-09 10:58:24.663: W/dalvikvm(343): VFY: unable to resolve static method 83: Lcom/google/common/base/Preconditions;.checkArgument (Z)V
04-09 10:58:24.663: D/dalvikvm(343): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0006
04-09 10:58:24.663: D/dalvikvm(343): VFY: dead code 0x0009-0009 in Lorg/ros/android/RosActivity;.startActivityForResult (Landroid/content/Intent;I)V
04-09 10:58:24.684: I/dalvikvm(343): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService; interface 142 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;'
04-09 10:58:24.684: W/dalvikvm(343): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;' failed
04-09 10:58:24.693: W/dalvikvm(343): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;)
04-09 10:58:24.693: I/dalvikvm(343): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService; interface 142 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;'
04-09 10:58:24.693: W/dalvikvm(343): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;' failed
04-09 10:58:24.693: W/dalvikvm(343): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;)
04-09 10:58:24.726: I/dalvikvm(343): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService; interface 142 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;'
04-09 10:58:24.726: W/dalvikvm(343): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;' failed
04-09 10:58:24.726: W/dalvikvm(343): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;)
04-09 10:58:24.753: I/dalvikvm(343): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService; interface 142 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;'
04-09 10:58:24.753: W/dalvikvm(343): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;' failed
04-09 10:58:24.753: I/dalvikvm(343): Could not find method org.ros.android.NodeRunnerService.addListener, referenced from method org.ros.android.RosActivity$NodeRunnerServiceConnection.onServiceConnected
04-09 10:58:24.753: W/dalvikvm(343): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 150: Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService;.addListener (Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerServiceListener;)V
04-09 10:58:24.753: D/dalvikvm(343): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0016
04-09 10:58:24.753: D/dalvikvm(343): VFY: dead code 0x0019-0033 in Lorg/ros/android/RosActivity$NodeRunnerServiceConnection;.onServiceConnected (Landroid/content/ComponentName;Landroid/os/IBinder;)V
04-09 10:58:24.841: I/dalvikvm(343): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/views/RosTextView; interface 141 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMain;'
04-09 10:58:24.844: W/dalvikvm(343): Link of class 'Lorg/ros/android/views/RosTextView;' failed
04-09 10:58:24.844: D/AndroidRuntime(343): Shutting down VM
04-09 10:58:24.844: W/dalvikvm(343): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.ros.tutorials.pubsub/org.ros.android.tutorial.pubsub.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class org.ros.android.views.RosTextView
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class org.ros.android.views.RosTextView
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at org.ros.android.tutorial.pubsub.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  ... 11 more
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ros.android.views.RosTextView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/org.ros.tutorials.pubsub-2.apk]
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  ... 20 more



---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31601/classnotfoundexception-on-pubsub-tutorial/) by [Sam_hon](https://answers.ros.org/users/2160/sam_hon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-04-10


Post score: 0

---

### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-04-17**:\
Just to clarify, have have you followed the documentation here?

http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/android_core/html/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your error starts here:

```
04-09 10:58:24.915: E/AndroidRuntime(343): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.ros.tutorials.pubsub/org.ros.android.tutorial.pubsub.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class org.ros.android.views.RosTextView
```

If you notice, you have both "org.ros.tutorials.pubsub" and "org.ros.tutoral.pubsub". (notice the extra/lack-of "s" in tutorials). Check to see if your spelling is correct.

Also, check the manifest to see if everything is in there and spelled correctly.

But I agree, first make sure you followed the instructions first:
http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/android_core/html/index.html

--Edit--

I may be completely wrong with this next part, but you have

```
04-09 10:58:24.684: I/dalvikvm(343): Failed resolving Lorg/ros/android/NodeRunnerService; interface 142 'Lorg/ros/node/NodeMainExecutor;'
```

Is it supposed to be "org" or "Lorg"?

---

Originally posted by [dberm22](https://answers.ros.org/users/4189/dberm22/) with karma: 93 on 2013-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0